# Create Labels or UIViews that will go through the main view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4

I was wondering what's the best way of making UIViews that will run through your main view Similar to the stock view in iPhone notification center (picture link below). What's the best practice? Any memory management required once the objects are out? Any tutorial link or explanation is appreciated. Ross

http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/iPhone-4S-Notification-Center.jpg

Comment: "UIView that will run through your main view".. umm.. what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: if you're looking for a stock ticker like marquee label, I've had success with these two controls in the past: 
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/marqueelabel 
And
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cltickerview

Comment: Sorry for confusing everyone. I mean a Marquee (As seen with the stock). I want a bunch of UIViews in a set roll across the screen.

Comment: I probably have to modify the MIT one cause mine will have as set of complex views as opposed to a text (Even more complex than the stock one). If you have any suggestions, I really appreciate it. Thanks again